# SQL View Shows same id once

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, view, group-by

I have two tables for storing information about persons. One Holds the username and adress information and the other holds multiple phone numbers linked with a foreign key to the users id. Now i want to create a view where the user only i shown on one line and in the phone number column all the phone numbers linked to lthe user should be listed. I have tried Full Join and it gives me the same user multiple times depending on how many phone number the user have.

Right now the code looks like this for creating the view

> CREATE VIEW StudentData AS
>       SELECT COALESCE(Students.FirstName + ' ', ' ') + COALESCE(Students.LastName, ' ') AS 'Name', 
>       COALESCE(Students.City + ', ', ' ') + COALESCE(Students.Country + ', ', ' ') + COALESCE(Phone.PhoneType, ' ') + 
>       COALESCE(Phone.PhoneNumber + ', ', ' ') + COALESCE(Students.StreetAdress + ', ', ' ') + COALESCE(CAST(Students.ZipCode AS varchar(10)), ' ')  AS 'Adress',
>       COALESCE(CAST(Students.Birthdate AS varchar(11)) + ', ', ' ') + COALESCE(Students.StudentType, ' ') AS 'Information'
>       FROM Students FULL JOIN Phone ON Students.StudentID = Phone.StudentID

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are some kludgy ways to do this (that depend on database system specifics usually, so please add a tag for your RDBMS). It would be better, if possible to do this *formatting* in a different layer rather than trying to do it in the database.

Comment: using STUFF it can be accomplished..

Comment: @UpvoteMarkAnswer - I always find it funny that people focus on `STUFF` as the "magic" way to do this when in fact, all that the `STUFF` call is responsible for is trimming the leading comma away. It's the `xml path` part that's more responsible for the concatenation.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable point @Mr.Damien_The_Unbeliever..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a string concatenation problem.  The query looks something like this in SQL Server:

```
create view v_userphone
    select u.username, u.address,
           stuff((select ','+phonenumber
                  from userphone up
                  where up.userid = u.userid
                  for xml path ('')
                 ), 1, 1, ''
                ) as phonenumbers
    from users u;
```